# Alinhamento de DIVS com CSS

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde galera, tenho uma dúvida em relação a alinhamento de div. Eu gostaria de deixar os itens do info 1 ao lado dos itens da info 2, como se fossem em blocos, e centralizados no meio da página, alguém consegue me ajudar por favor?

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="infos">
      <div>
        <h3 class="info">XX</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 class="info">XX</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#"><h3 class="info">XX</h3></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#"<h3class="info">XX</h3></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

**Sua solução é utilizar o flex box**

veja abaixo o seu código porém com algumas modificações, as opções de GRID como o ROW e COL, você consegue visualizar e entender melhor estudando um pouco do [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Com CDN bootstrap:

```css
    .info  {
        margin-bottom: 2%;
        background-color: gainsboro;
        margin-right: 1%;
        margin-top: 5%;
        padding: 25px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col info ">
            <h3 class="info">info 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col info ">
            <h3 class="info">info 2</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex">
        <div class="col info ">
            <h3 class="info">info 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col info ">
            <h3 class="info">info 4</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Sem a CDN bootstrap - fica meio bugado, recomendo usar biblioteca como a do bootstrap:

```css
.info {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: gainsboro;
        margin: 5%;
        padding: 25px;
        flex-grow: 2;
    }
    .flex {
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row flex">
        <div class="col info ">
            <h3 class="info">info 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col info ">
            <h3 class="info">info 2</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex">
        <div class="col info ">
            <h3 class="info">info 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col info ">
            <h3 class="info">info 4</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: não adicionei os links, mas você pode adicionar a tag <a> </a> para linkar seus blocos de informações (DIVS)

assim: <div class="row">
        <div class="col center-block">
            <a href="#"><h3 class="info">XX</h3></a>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: cara seguir o que você pediu, alinhei info 1 com info 2 e info 3 com info 4, seguindo a lógica seria isso, basta você ver o código para adaptar